# Enable tracemalloc, Can't launch electrumx server

Tags: python, server, cryptocurrency

Hi i have installed electrumx server (https://github.com/spesmilo/electrumx) but when i have problem with launching it.

user@user:~$sudo systemctl status electrumx

```
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/electrumX-1.15.0-py3.7.egg/electrumx/server/storage.py", line 31, in __init__
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]:     self.open(name, create=self.is_new)
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/electrumX-1.15.0-py3.7.egg/electrumx/server/storage.py", line 83, in open
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]:     max_open_files=mof)
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]:   File "plyvel/_plyvel.pyx", line 247, in plyvel._plyvel.DB.__init__
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]:   File "plyvel/_plyvel.pyx", line 94, in plyvel._plyvel.raise_for_status
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]: plyvel._plyvel.Error: b'NotFound: utxo/LOCK: No such file or directory'
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp-4.0.0a1-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/aiohttp/client.py:977: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'noop' was never aw
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]:   self._resp.release()
Jul 27 13:56:11 dev-electrumx-ltc electrumx_server[16179]: RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Should i enable something? I would hugly appreciate any hint.